# How to modify a pandas dataframe using broadcasting series on a subset of columns

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, broadcasting

Given the following table:

```
 import numpy as np
 import pandas as pd
 data = pd.DataFrame(data = np.arange(16).reshape((4, 4)),
                     index = ['Chile', 'Argentina', 'Peru', 'Bolivia'],
                     columns = ['one', 'two', 'three', 'four'])


           one  two three  four
 Chile      0    1   2      3
 Argentina  4    5   6      7
 Peru       8    9   10     11
 Bolivia    12   13  14     15
```

I want to apply an operation through broadcasting a pandas series over a subset of the columns (`one` and `three`) that will **modify** (update) the table. So..

```
ser_to_broad = pd.Series([1, 2], index = ['one', 'three'])
data + ser_to_broad

           one  two three  four
Chile       1   NaN   4     NaN
Argentina   5   NaN   8     NaN    
Peru        9   NaN   12    NaN    
Bolivia     13  NaN   16    NaN
```

Does there exist a way to preserve the original values of columns `two` and `four` with the broadcasting approach?

Comment: So you want to update `data`?

Comment: Yes, the idea is mutate the table with the operation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to update data, I think this would do:

```
ser_to_broad = pd.Series([1, 2], index=['one', 'three'])
data[ser_to_broad.index] += ser_to_broad

print(data)
```

**Output**

```
           one  two  three  four
Chile        1    1      4     3
Argentina    5    5      8     7
Peru         9    9     12    11
Bolivia     13   13     16    15
```

Comment: This answer is more generalizable because it doesn't require to neutralize the operation in the other columns filling the series with values. My only issue is that the broadcasting operation is more difficult to read given the slice operations.

Answer (score 1):

Doing with `reindex`, since there is miss columns in `ser_to_broad`, then it will return `NaN` (`NaN` + somevalue=`NaN`)

```
data+ser_to_broad.reindex(data.columns,fill_value=0)
Out[106]: 
           one  two  three  four
Chile        1    1      4     3
Argentina    5    5      8     7
Peru         9    9     12    11
Bolivia     13   13     16    15
```

Comment: It reads like you ought to be able to do this with .add but its NotImplemented:

Comment: Good approach. Indeed, @AndyHayden I thought that .add has deal with these situation

Comment: @AndyHayden First thing came into my mind is `add` , however, seems it is not support for this situation .

Comment: @Wen-Ben an issue with your approach is that require to fill the series with a value that neutralize the operation in the columns `two` and `four`. For example, if the operation instead of `data + ser` was `data * ser` we need to fill the series with ones.

Comment: @CristóbalAlcázar yes that is correct , different operation may need different fill